# Powershell outputs on a C# .NET Environment

Tags: c#, powershell

I was trying to invoke powershell commands in a c# .net environment and manipulate the outputs, for example: I would like to iterate through each parent and child nodes and get their Innertext value and map them into my classes, but all I get is the whole xml content: below is my code so far:

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
Pipeline pipe = rs.CreatePipeline();

//create powershell
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    //Add the commnads to the PowerShell object.
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Content").AddArgument("C:\\XMLFileSettings.xml");
    try
    {
        foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.ToString());
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot parse the XML in C#?

Comment: `Get-Content` returns a the contents of a file in a string array, so the result you're seeing is correct. Question is, why are you opening powershell to manipulate an XML file when there are multiple ways to do that with `C#`?

Comment: I was just curious, now that you mentioned that Get-Content returns an array of string, which means it would be very difficult to manipulate. Ill just try to use c# code instead.